# How to remove fabric.js object with custom id?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have created a fabric.js canvas editor with some images and texts. but I want to track added images or texts. That's why I provide myId when added this object. But how to remove the object with this custom id?

Here is my code for adding a text

```
var text = new fabric.Text(txt, { left: 30, top: 0, fill: "#"+col , fontFamily: family, id:MyID });
canvas.setActiveObject(text);
canvas.add(text);
```

Here **myID** is my custom id

But how to remove this text by using this myID ?
I have tried

```
canvas.remove(get_myID); //where get_myID is provided id by code
```

but it does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

I've extended the Fabric library for doing a similar function.

First, create a file, `fabricExtensions.js` and include it just after you have loaded the fabric library in the head section of your page.

```
  <!-- Load FabricJS Library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fabric.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Load FabricJS Extension file -->
  <!-- ** Load this file in the HEAD AFTER loading FabricJS** -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fabricExtensions.js"></script>
```

Inside the newly created `fabricExtensions.js` file add the following code:

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.getItemByAttr = function(attr, name) {
    var object = null,
    objects = this.getObjects();
    for (var i = 0, len = this.size(); i < len; i++) {
        if (objects[i][attr] && objects[i][attr] === name) {
            object = objects[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return object;
};
```

What this block of code does, is it allows you to select an object by any attribute assigned to it.

Now, to remove the object, this should work:

```
canvas.fabric.getItemByAttr('id', myID).remove();
```

---

That method will allow you to target ANY attribute set to an object.  Alternatively, you could change it to something like this to target only the exact attribute you were looking for:

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.getItemByMyID = function(myID) {
    var object = null,
        objects = this.getObjects();
    for (var i = 0, len = this.size(); i < len; i++) {
        if (objects[i].id&& objects[i].id=== myID) {
            object = objects[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return object;
};
```

And to remove the object:

```
canvas.fabric.getItemByMyID(myID).remove();
```

Comment: great post
one comment - calling the script 
canvas.getItemByAttr('id', myID).remove();

Comment: I love this answer. Nice extension, very clean!

I am calling using *canvas.getItemByAttr('configId', configId).remove();*

Comment: `canvas.remove(canvas.getItemByMyID(myID))` instead of `canvas.fabric.getItemByMyID(myID).remove();` worked at least for images

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy to remove an object with a custom attribute. Use .find() to find the object that matches your custom attribute value. In my case, I had an attribute called "layerId". Then call canvas.remove(obj), and it should remove your object.

```
let obj = canvas.getObjects().find(obj => obj.layerId === customId);
canvas.remove(obj);
```

Comment: Hello Austin, perhaps you could give the OP some insight into your code? Why is the answer you provided a good answer and how does it tackle the issue the OP has asked about? Walk the OP through the logic so they understand what you have wrote.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @dalelandry. Code only answer may be deleted by high rep users. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I achieve the same functionality. I have two methods, getObjectFromCanvasById and removeObjectFromCanvas.
getObjectFromCanvasById takes an id (the id you set (MyID) when creating a canvas object)

```
getObjectFromCanvasById(id) {
    const canvasObject = window.canvas.getObjects().filter((item) => {
        return item.id === parseInt(id)
    })
    return canvasObject[0]
}
```

I call this function from my removeObjectFromCanvas method

```
removeObjectFromCanvas(objectId) {
    const canvasObject = this.getObjectFromCanvasById(objectId)
    window.canvas.remove(canvasObject)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 :

```
// to get object properties

console.log(canvas.getObjects());
```

step 2:

```
canvas.item(1).visible = true;

//by the reference of index number item(index number here).visible = true or false
```

step 3:

```
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call it like `canvas.remove(text)`. Or you can use `text.remove()` or `canvas.getActiveObject().remove()`.

Comment: No i want to remove it by my custom id.. is it Possible?

Comment: @Softcare, what about `canvas.getActiveObject().remove()`?

Comment: Actually i wanted to do this by not selecting any layer.. just on  a button click.. this buttons store my custom ids..

Comment: @Softcare, what about using `canvas.getObjects()` and checking on each iteration if `it.id == myId`?

Comment: yah it could be nice.. could you provide some sample codes for this

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < canvas.getObjects().length; ++i) { if (canvas.item(i).id == MyID) {canvas.item(i).remove(); break;}}`

Answer (score 0):

this answer is a rework of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32953690/1815624

I wanted to remove the item by id...I think things have changed a little since the original answer was given you now remove items like this `canvas.remove( object);`

here's the code

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.RemoveByMyID = function(myID) {
    var object = null,
        objects = this.getObjects();
    for (var i = 0, len = this.size(); i < len; i++) {
        if (objects[i].id&& objects[i].id=== myID) {
            object = objects[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    canvas.remove( object);
};
```

and how to use it

```
canvas.RemoveByMyID(myID);
```